# Copying file in node.js build script

Tags: node.js, build, copy

Im playing around with a javascript project, it uses a node build script.

It syncing some folders into a built folder via

```
try {
  fs.statSync('built/imgs');
} catch(err) {
  if (err.code=='ENOENT') fs.symlinkSync('../imgs', 'built/imgs');
  else throw err;
}
```

Whats the corresponding fs command to get a real copy of the files to the built folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no function in the `fs` object that will copy a whole directory.  There's not even one that will copy a whole file.

However, this is a quick and easy way to copy one file.

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.createReadStream('input_filename').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('output_filename'));
```

Now you just need to get a directory list.  You would use the `fs.readdir` or `fs.readdirSync` for that.

So to copy a directory to another you might do something like this:

```
var dir = fs.readdirSync('.');
for (var i=0; i < dir.length; i++) {
    fs.createReadStream(dir[i]).pipe(fs.createWriteStream("newpath/"+dir[i]));
}
```